# Intercepting touch events in ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using Jake Wharton's [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com) on my FragmentActivity which contains a viewpager. I am having difficulty intercepting onTouch events. I know the the ViewPagerIndicator intercepts all touch events to the ViewPager, but I have had no success with setting an onTouchListener to either my ViewPager or my ViewIndicator. Here's my basic setup:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new ViewSliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);PageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
....
}
```

Thanks for your help, I'm sure its something stupid but I've googled a ton and been tinkering with this for hours and can't seem to get anywhere with it.

and As ive said, I've tried things like:

```
mPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

with both ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator with no success.

Comment: I also have not find any solution is there any one can help???

Comment: you should start bounty @benbeel !!!!!!!!!

Comment: take a look brief explanation  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23016638/2236219